# How select rows where field is not null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have relationship between two tables: Blog, Images.

**Blog Model**

```
public function images(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\ImageBlog', 'id_blog', 'id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$lastPosts = Blog::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('images')->take(3)->get();
```

So, how can I get last three rows where `images` is not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method:

```
$lastPosts = Blog::orderBy('id', 'desc')->has('images')->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: $lastPosts = Blog::orderBy('id', 'desc')->has('images')->with('images')->take(3)->get();

Answer (score 1):

Another optimize way of getting post with images is as follows

```
  $lastPosts=Blog::orderBy('id','desc')
         ->with(array('images'=>function($query){
                      $query->select('id','image'....);
                }))->take(3)->get();
```

Here in $query->select() you can pass only those column name which are required from image table instead of getting whole data so it will reduce your response time.